# Is there a way to link javascript to a certain style in the external css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Is there a way to link javascript to a certain style in the css?** 
 Here is an example of what I want to do:
syntax onclick="[change style to external stylesheet class-for example **changes**]". Is there a special function to do this.?

```
 changes { /*just an example, i know i can do this is css and html only*/
 background-img:url("");
 }
```

Please comment if you need more information.

Comment: please add some pseudo code, an example will help. also, seems like you are into manipulations - so jquery is a good place to start

Comment: Try .addClass() function

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? It is difficult to understand your problem now ?

Comment: does the edit help in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample.css

```
.rednode{
  background-color: red;
}
.bluenode{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

In JS,

```
function changeClass(node) {
 node.classList.remove("rednode");
 node.classList.add("bluenode");
}
```

In HTML,

```
<span class='rednode' onclick='changeClass(this)'/>
```

Comment: I think this is a really good way of doing what i intended, thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do

```
onclick="this.style='color: red;';"
```

if that's what you want.

You would put it in an HTML element:

```
<p style="" onclick="this.style='color: red;';">Some text</p>
```

Or, if you want to link to a class or id:

```
<p class="" onclick="this.class='red';">Some text</p>
```

With the external css file having:

```
.red { color: red;
     }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks - this works and i was looking for something like this but I forgot you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Add class` `Remove Class`

Here I will show one Example ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#RC").click(function(){
    $("p").removeClass("intro");
  });
$("#AC").click(function(){
    $("p").addClass("intro");
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.intro
{
font-size:120%;
color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="intro">Add Class Remove Class Example</p>

<button id="RC">Remove Class</button>
<button id="AC">Add Class</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this.. It may Help you !

Comment: thanks, this works but i was looking at just using javascript at the moment

Comment: You can't expect that everybody is using jQuery.